# Slang Meanings of Grünes and Weißes?

Tags: usage, colloquial, slang

I was listening to Ufo361, and heard the lyric(s):

Ja, du weißt, wo ich wohn'

Wo du dein Grünes und dein Weißes holst, jaja

Du weißt, wo ich wohn' (ja, du weißt)

Wo du dein Grünes und dein Weißes holst, jaja (ja, du weißt, ja)

361, Dicka, ja (361, Dicka)

361, Dicka (ja, ja, ja)

(Full lyrics [here](https://play.google.com/music/preview/T3hmzl4lrwgnsdsyvikndfruuem?lyrics=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=lyrics&pcampaignid=kp-lyrics&u=0#))

Trying to understand the song better, I looked up the words "Weißes" and "Grünes" in Leo ([here](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/Wei%C3%9Fes) and [here](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/Gr%C3%BCnes), respectively.). Getting what I assumed were literal (v.s. slang/colloquial) results, I then looked them up in Superslang.de and MundMische.de, again not finding (relevant) results. As such, what do Grünes and Weißes mean? Are they just what they appear in the dictionary, or do they have another, slang, meaning?

Note: I thought that it could mean drugs based on the context, but I am not sure. Thanks for all help!

--

Edit: added tags

Edit 2: Extended lyrics given

Comment: *Grün und Weiß* are the (older) colors of the German Police. These lines in that song are about people yelling at drug users "I know where you live, I will call the police."

Comment: It would be helpful to have not only the one line of text but, say, four lines up and four lines down, for context.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann I did so, thank you for the recommendation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It simply refers to the color of the drugs. You were assuming the right thing.

"Grünes" is obviously weed, and "Weißes" is something like cocaine or amphetamine.